# click() jquery not works in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have this scenario:

```
<div class="nextMediumImg"></div>
<a class="next" rel="history" title="successiva" href="#4">
  <img src="images/next_image.png" width="13" height="27" alt="Successiva">
</a>
```

When I click div(class="nextMediumImg"), occurs event click in image (class="next")

this is jquery

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.nextMediumImg').click(function () {
            $('.next img').click();
            });
         });
    </script>
```

This jquery works correctly in Chrome, Firefox but NOT in IE8. How can I solve this strange issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: change `$('.next img').click();` to `$('.next').click();` works?

Comment: Open your console in IE8 (push F12 to open developer tools) and take a look at what error message you get.

Comment: Are you sure you want to click on the image and not on the anchor tag?

Comment: If I click directly on the image not work in Chrome

Comment: The very likely answer is you have something else in your JS that is broken in IE8 and is causing your scripts to stop executing before these handlers even get applied. Please open your console (F12), refresh your page, and tell us the error that you see.

Comment: I dont get errors with console in IE :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in IE 8 with jQuery 1.10.1, I dont see any issue. Save this code as .html and open in IE 8.

**If not work, then you should be using jQuery 2.X which has dropped a support for IE 8 :)**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.nextMediumImg{
    height:20px; width:50px; display:block; background-color:orange;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.next img').click(function(){alert('yeah');});
          $('.nextMediumImg').click(function () {
            $('.next img').click();
            });
         });   
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nextMediumImg"></div>
<a class="next" rel="history" title="successiva" href="#4">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4c05b8240ce655d4db67b1eb99f705d7?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" width="13" height="27" alt="Successiva">
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @vincenzolopalo, I opened in IE 8 and checked in all the document modes like 7,8,quirks. Its works for me. what exact version of IE do you use

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, you set the click to the `img` and not to the `anchor`.

Change

```
$('.next img').click();
```

to

```
$('.next').click();
```

should work.

Comment: Do you click the `div` box or the image? Have you set the size of the div box? because its empty..and maybe not visible?

Comment: How can you possibly just guess that that will solve the problem without knowing what the source of the problem is?

Comment: Thats the reason why i ask him?